# React.js row.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a problem with creating react table, acctualy i have this code

```
render() {
    var tableData = [
      {name: this.state.users}
    ];
    var tableRow = [];
     for(var x = 1; x <= this.state.users.lenght; x++) {
    tableRow.push(this.state.users[x]);
    if (x % 4 == 0) {
        tableData.push(tableRow);
        tableRow = [];
    }
}

    return (
        <Table1>
        {tableData.map((row, index) => {
            return (
                <tr key={row + index}>
                    {row.map((cell, index) => {
                        return (
                            <td key={"cell_" + index}>{cell}</td>
                        );
                    })}
                </tr>
            );
        })}
   </Table1>
```

in my `tableData` i have some firebase data which is retrieved properly, but i have a problem with placing it to table cell, actually with this table code i got an error "TypeError: row.map is not a function" How can i solve that? Thanks :)

edit:
added console.log for tableData
[image]

Comment: can you `console.log(tableData)` and show us the result ?

Comment: added it to question :)

Comment: `this.state.users.lenght` -> `this.state.users.length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` is a method of Arrays, and `tableData[0]` isn’t an Array, it’s an Object (`{name: this.state.users}`). It’s not clear what that’s doing in there, maybe you can remove it? `tableData[1]` onwards will all be Arrays and should render correctly.

Comment: Well, i think that i cant remove it :) how can i make tableData as an array? ;)

Comment: `tableData` is an array but the first item in it is not. You’re doing `tableData.map( row => row.map( ... ))` which means every `row` must be an array as well. But the first `row` is an object. I can’t say how to change it to an array because I don’t know what it’s for. Why did you decide to put it in the array?

Comment: Lets say im retrieving usernames from firebase database, i want to put them all to table and make them clickable to retrieve clicked user data, i have read that putting data to array would be the best option to do that :) thanks for your time by the way

Comment: Try this: instead of `var tableData = [{name: this.state.users}]` just write `var tableData = []`. Does it render now? Is anything missing?

Comment: It displays usernames but in one cel only, also, there are 4 of them in database, while app displays only 3, so one is missing

Comment: That’s because your loop starts at 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `tableData` contains the first value as `{name: this.state.users}` which isn't an array and hence row.map will fail.

Secondly, there is a typo in `length`

```
for(var x = 1; x <= this.state.users.length; x++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

`.map` is available only on Arrays and in your case `row` is not also arrays `(tableData[0] is not array)`.